# What is Reactive Extensions used for

Tags: silverlight, system.reactive

An MVC 3 web site with some sections in Silverlight 5

- Can Rx be used in this scenario?
- If so, how and which components of the
  application can benefit

Comment: Can you tell us more about what your website is doing? Rx doesn't directly apply to MVC3 in the core pipeline...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [pre-release documentation for Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) has just been released, so I recommend that you take a look at that, and in particular this section: [When Will You Use Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242982%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).