# How and where can Reactive Extensions be used?

Tags: system.reactive, silverlight-5.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Reactive Extensions used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322626/what-is-reactive-extensions-used-for)

Lets say for instance I am building an eCommerce web site.

In layman's terms, where can Rx be used and what will it be doing?

SilverLight 5 and Rx, are there any practical examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pre-release documentation for Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242985%28v=VS.103%29.aspx) has just been released, so I recommend that you take a look at that, and in particular this section: [When Will You Use Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242982%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Apart from documentation available I would recommend viewing training videos on www.pluralsight.com

Answer (score 2):

I briefly discuss some of the core application usage types at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Post.aspx/Title/Reactive-Framework-Why-bother. I also have a number of Silverlight samples available at http://www.thinqlinq.com/Files.aspx.